# Click events in Sencha touch

Tags: listview, checkbox, sencha-touch

I have checkboxes in my list item, I want to handle both( checkbox check/uncheck and list item click) these events separately. How can I do this?? I am new to sencha touch, please help me.
For now I am able to click on the checkboxes but the listItemTap event is getting called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the event parameter to get the target, like this:-

```
itemTapFn: function(list, index, target, record, e) {

    if (e.target.type === 'checkbox') {
        /* checkbox click functionality */
    } else {
        /* do itemtap functionality */
    }

}
```